# how to expose rasa server to slack with docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, slack, rasa

is there a way to expose rasa server with docker to slack without using ngrok (am using traefik), and i exposed it to "https://rasa.dev.x-hub.io" so when i try:
https://rasa.dev.x-hub.io/webhooks/slack/webhook
i get no response. as you can see below, everything is working fine.

**rasa server:**

(*ignore tensorflow error*)
[image]

**action server:**

[image]

**duckling:**

[image]

and the following is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  rasa:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xhub-org/p/xpeers/slackbot:{{img_version}}
    container_name: rasa
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:rasa.dev.x-hub.io
      - traefik.port={{app_port}}
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.enable=true
    restart: always
    networks: ['rasa-network']
    command:
      - run
      - --cors
      - "*"
      - --enable-api
      - --log-file
      - out.log
      - --connector
      - slack
      - --credentials
      - slack_credentials.yml
      - --endpoints
      - endpoints.yml
      - -m
      - /models
    depends_on:
      - action_server

  action_server:  
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xhub-org/p/xpeers/slackbot:{{img_version}}
    container_name: rasa_action_1
    networks: ['rasa-network']
    command :
      - run
      - actions

  duckling:
    image: rasa/duckling:latest
    networks: ['rasa-network']
    ports:
      - "8005:8005"

networks: {rasa-network: {}}
```

am also using **Docker Container Registry integrated into GitLab**, every project can
have its own space to store its Docker images.

Any help please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved my problem by adding :

```
networks:
  - web
  - rasa-network
```

and :

```
networks:
  rasa-network:
  web:
    external: true
```

**Full update:**

```
version: "2"
services:
  rasa:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xhub-org/p/xpeers/slackbot:{{img_version}}
    container_name: rasa
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:rasa.dev.x-hub.io
      - traefik.port={{services.rasa.app_port}}
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.enable=true
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
      - rasa-network
    command:
      - run
      - --cors
      - "*"
      - --enable-api
      - --log-file
      - out.log
      - --connector
      - slack
      - --credentials
      - slack_credentials.yml
      - --endpoints
      - endpoints.yml
      - -m
      - /models
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
    depends_on:
      - action_server

  action_server:  
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xhub-org/p/xpeers/slackbot:{{img_version}}
    container_name: rasa_action_1
    networks:
      - rasa-network
    command :
      - run
      - actions
    ports:
      - "5055:5055"

  duckling:
    image: rasa/duckling:latest
    networks: ['rasa-network']
    ports:
      - "8005:8005"

networks:
  rasa-network:
  web:
    external: true
```